# When do I need to use self.instance_method vs instance_method alone?

Tags: ruby, class, instance-methods

I'm hoping someone can explain why I get the same behavior from both of these methods and what that means for when to or not to use self.

```
def my_instance_method(arg)
  'execute some code' if another_instance_method_of_same_class?(arg)
end
```

seems to behave exactly the same as

```
def my_instance_method(arg)
  'execute some code' if self.another_instance_method_of_same_class?(arg)
end
```

My apologies if my search skills aren't up to par but I couldn't find the exact answer to this question, just explanations of what self does (which made me think I should need it).
I'm using the latest version of Ruby. Thank you.

Comment: From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver): _"`self` is the default receiver. If you don't specify any receiver `self` will be used"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few differences between `self.foo(...)` and `foo(...)`, but they're mostly equivalent.

## Privacy

`private` methods can only be called via `foo` directly, and never with an explicit receiver. So if `foo` is marked `private`, then you *have* to call it without `self`.

```
class Example

  private def foo(x)
    x + 1
  end

  def bar
    foo # Works fine
    self.foo # Error: foo is private
  end

end
```

## Shadowing

If you have a local variable called `foo` in the current function, then writing `foo` *without arguments* will reference the local variable instead

```
class Example

  def foo(*args)
    puts "Hello :)"
  end

  def bar
    foo = 100 # Just an ordinary variable; no relation to the above method
    foo # This refers to the local variable called "foo"
    self.foo # This calls the method foo() with no arguments
    foo(1) # This calls the method foo() with one argument
    self.foo(1) # Equivalent to the above; calls with one argument
  end

  def baz
    foo # There's no local variable called "foo", so this calls the method
  end

end
```

## Assignment

If the method you're talking about is an assignment method (i.e. ends in `=`), then it must always be called with an explicit receiver

```
class Example

  def foo=(value)
    puts "Assigning foo = #{value}"
  end

  def bar
    foo = 0 # This creates a new local variable called foo and assigns to it
    self.foo = 0 # Calls foo= on self
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks. So would it be correct to assume that in the last example of a setter method/ assignment method, that @foo and self.foo would be equivalent?

Comment: If the `foo=` method was generated with `attr_writer` then yes. But, of course, `def foo=` can do anything an ordinary function can do if defined explicitly, so in general `self.foo = 1` is just a function call like any other.

Comment: @Ryder the last example actually shows that they are _not_ equivalent. The `foo=` method just prints some message without setting the `@foo` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question, but that will not help you understand when you are to use the prefix `self.` when defining methods. I therefore need to first present some background information on *instance methods*.

Suppose we have the following class definition.

```
class C
  puts "self = #{self}

  def i
    puts "self in i = #{self}"
    "i"
  end

  def self.c
    puts "self in c = #{self}"
    "c"
  end

  singleton_class.define_method(:s) do
    puts "self in s = #{self}"
    "s"
  end
end
  #=> :s
  self = C
```

I have defined an instance method `C#i`, a class method `C::c` and an instance method on `C` singleton class, `s`.

Note that, since `self #=> C` within the class, writing `def self.c ...` is precisely the same as `def C.c ...`. The only reasons for writing `self` is that if we rename the class we don't have to change `def self.c ...` and
"self" is harder to misspell than, say, "PhilharmonicOrchestras".

Unsurprisingly,

```
C.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:i]
instance = C.new
  #=> #<C:0x00007ff0011074f0>
instance.i
  #=> "i"
  self in i = #<C:0x00007ff0011074f0>
```

Now consider the last two methods:

```
C.methods(false)
  #=> [:s, :c]
C.c
  #=> "c"
  self in c = C
```

```
C.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:s, :c]
C.s
  #=> "s"
  self in s = C
```

This shows that defining a method `def self.class.c` is merely a shorthand way of telling Ruby that you wish to create an *instance method* `s` on `C`'s singleton class. Similarly, references to "class methods" are shorthand for those same instance methods. In fact, there is no need to define methods with the prefix `self.`. You could instead use `singleton_class` and `define_method`, as I have done, or elect one of several other ways, the most common being

```
class C
  class << self
    def s
      puts "self in s = #{self}"
      "s"
    end
  end
end
```

where `class << self .. end` causes `self` to change from `C` to `C.singleton_class`.

---

You defined a method which I will modify a bit:

```
self
  #=> main

def my_instance_method
  puts "self = #{self}, self.class = #{self.class}"
  'execute some code'
end
```

```
my_instance_method
  #=> "execute some code"
  self = main, self.class = Object
```

As all methods are instance methods this must be one as well, namely a private instance method of `Object`:

```
Object.private_instance_methods.include?(:my_instance_method)
  #=> true
```

Being a private instance method we cannot invoke it on an explicit receiver that is an instance of `Object` (`main`), but we can write:

```
Object.new.send(:my_instance_method)
  #=> "execute some code"
  self = #<Object:0x00007f988514e180>, self.class = Object
```

Note that if it were made a public method it would be available for use by all objects, which obviously would lead to disaster.

Next consider:

```
def self.your_instance_method
  puts "self = #{self}, self.class = #{self.class}"
  'execute some code'
end
```

```
your_instance_method
  #=> "execute some code"
  self = main, self.class = Object
```

This method must be defined on `self`'s (`main`'s) singleton class, which we may confirm:

```
self.singleton_class.instance_methods.include?(:your_instance_method)
  #=> true
```

Therefore, the implicit receiver of

```
your_instance_method
```

is `self`, which equals `main`, giving the same result as

```
self.send(:your_instance_method)
```

This is a complicated subject (concerning Ruby's [Object Model](https://makandracards.com/makandra/496030-the-ruby-object-model)), particularly for someone fairly new to Ruby, so don't be concerned if you are not able to follow all of what I have said.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't understand everything, but I will revisit this answer after I've learned a bit more and maybe I will understand it after gaining more context. Also worried this comment might not be appropriate for this site based on the guidelines but feels rude to not say anything. Thank you for the detailed write up.